# Proof structure validity: assume (a), (b), show (c). Then Permute.

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I am given a collection of sets $\mathcal{E}$ and am trying to prove it is an elementary family. To show $\mathcal{E}$ is an elementary family I must show that it satisfies the following properties:

**(a)** $\emptyset \in \mathcal{E}$

**(b)** If $A$, $B$ $\in \mathcal{E}$, then $A\cap B \in \mathcal{E}$

**(c)** If $A \in \mathcal{E}$ then $A^{c}$ is a finite disjoint union of members of $\mathcal{E}$

I am thinking about structuring my proof as follows:

**Step 1:** Show that if $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(a)** and **(b)** then $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(c)**.

**Step 2:** Show that if $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(a)** and **(c)** then $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(b)**.

**Step 3:** Show that if $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(b)** and **(c)** then $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies **(a)**.

What I want to know is if the above three steps is enough to prove that $\mathcal{E}$ must satisfy **(a)**, **(b)** and **(c)** (and thus is an elementary family)? If this is valid, is there a name for this kind of proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid proof technique. For example let (a) (b) and (c) be statements as follows:

(a) all real numbers are negative and the reals are closed under multiplication

(b) a negative real times a negative real is a positive real

(c) there are no real numbers.

(a)&(b) imply (c) by contradiction.
(a)&(c) imply (b) vacuously(nothing to check)
(b)&(c) imply (a) vacuously(again nothing to check.)

But, even though (b) is true, (a) and (c) definitely aren't, showing your argument is formally flawed.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this example. How does the assumption of (a) and (b) imply there are no real numbers? Is this a typo?

Comment: No typo. Assume there is a real number x.Then x*x is also a real number since the reals are closed under multiplication. Since all reals are negative, x is negative. Then by (b) x*x is positive. Since all real numbers are negative, x*x is not real, a contradiction. Thus there are no real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\cal E$ which satisfies *none* the three properties. Then each implication holds vacuously, since $(\varphi_1\land\varphi_2)\rightarrow\varphi_3$ is true whenever $\varphi_1$ or $\varphi_2$ are false (and here all three are false).

In order to show that a specific family $\cal E$ has these three properties, you need to show that it has these three properties. There's no way around it. You can show that it in fact a family with *better* properties which imply the ones you want, sure, but that's a different story.